# Apply IF(), ISNUMBER() and/or SEARCH() to extract text from string

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have the following datasheet

[image]

As you can see, `Column C` contain both the patient's sex and age. I would like `Column D` to show 0 if C contain "M" (equal to male) and 1 if C contain "F" (equal to female).

I tried

```
=IF(SEARCH("M";C2;C2);1;0)
```

But that did not work.

Or, even better, is it possible to split the `C-column` so that it generates two columns, one with patient's sex and one with age?

Comment: Select the column, then use Data - Text to Columns, specify the data is Delimited, and choose a Space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using a loop
F2:F3 list to be searched (Write M and F in these)
C2 cell to be searched

=INDEX($F$2:$F$3,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($F$2:$F$3,C2)),-1,1)*(ROW($F$2:$F$33)-ROW(F$2)+1)))
```

after you write the formula in column D **make sure press Shift + Ctrl + Enter** as this formula uses Array search

and for even better technique to split Age and Sex , use **Text to Column** option under Data tab in excel and use Delimeter as 'Space'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("M",A1), -9)>0, 1, IF(IFERROR(FIND("F",A1), -9)>0, 0))
```

[image]